# Error creating bean with name 'rabbitListenerContainerFactory'

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, zipkin

I have a spring boot microservice: Zuul-api-gateway-server, and I am trying to implement a Zipkin server listening to rabbitmq for logging messages within the microservice.

I have added the following dependencies to this microservice:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have started the Zipkin server using the following commands:

SET RABBIT_URI=amqp://localhost
java -jar zipkin.jar

I then try to start up the microservice however I get the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
>       at com.shopping.sandbox.netflixzuulapigatewayserver.NetflixZuulApiGatewayServerApplication.main(NetflixZuulApiGatewayServerApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory.getAdviceChain(AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory.java:198) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at brave.spring.rabbit.SpringRabbitTracing.decorateSimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(SpringRabbitTracing.java:170) ~[brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit-5.4.4.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.SleuthRabbitBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.0.M2.jar:2.1.0.M2]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1737) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       ... 20 common frames omitted

Comment: Did you copy paste your pom entries correctly? The correct artifactId for Sleuth Zipkin is `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin`

Answer (score 2):

As there is a bug in Spring AMQP, which will be fixed in Release 2.1.3 
**[Issue link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-846)**

For a tempory fix, you can enable retry properties to create advice chain.

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
```

Hope this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, changing Spring Boot version to 2.1.0.RELEASE did the trick for me. You should try it too. There must be something wrong with  RabbitMQ in Spring Boot version 2.1.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

add build.gradle

> apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

springBootVersion=2.1.3.RELEASE
springCloudVersion=Greenwich.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

this ok